# Kentico Document/TreeNode Macro Namespace

Tags: kentico

When [creating/registering a custom macro](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/macro-expressions/extending-the-macro-engine/registering-custom-macro-methods) that targets a `TreeNode` parameter (CurrentDocument), what macro namespace can/should be targeted so that users can access the members of the namespace when writing macro expressions against `TreeNode` objects?

The [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/macro-expressions/extending-the-macro-engine/registering-custom-macro-methods) provides examples such as `StringNamespace` and `SystemNamespace`, what should be used for `TreeNode` objects?

The custom macro is registered in the following fashion. It takes a parameter of `TreeNode` and ideally will be used with infix notation like `{% CurrentDocument.Foobar() %}` in a web part.

```
[assembly: RegisterExtension(typeof(MacroMethods), typeof(TreeNode))]
public class MacroMethods : MacroMethodContainer
{
    [MacroMethod(typeof(string), "Generates a string.", 1)]
    [MacroMethodParam(0, "CurrentDocument", typeof(TreeNode), "The current rendered document.")]
    public static object Foobar(EvaluationContext context, params object[] parameters)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not possible as you would need to extend the `TreeNode` class itself. I'm also looking at the source code and the `DocumentContext` is being registered in a different way then the custom macro methods/namespaces/properties are. It is not using the `MacroMethodContainer`, but an `AbstractContext` which cannot be extended without source code.

However, even if this would be possible, I would highly recommended not to do this. It is against best practises to mix your custom code with Kentico code. What I would recommend to do is to create a custom macro namespace & put all your methods/properties there.

In the end you will be able to call all your macros such as:

```
{% MyCoolMacros.Foobar() %}
```

Comment: To avoid creating a custom namespace, would @Shof answer of just using `CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentContext.CurrentDocument` within the method's respective code be a better approach to target the currently rendered document? If not, should I be targeting a different type for the TreeNode parameter to get access to the currently rendered document?

Comment: Shofs example shows class that is used to get CurrentDocument from within C# code (not macro!). However, if you do need to get current document using macro, you can simply write {% CurrentDocument.DocumentName %} or any other property. I didn't think this is what you were asking though.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have to pass CurrentDocument as a parameter. You  can access CurrentDocument within macro with `CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentContext.CurrentDocument`